# Wpf Livecharts - Separator step value binding is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, separator, livecharts

Simply I want to add an X-axis separator with dynamic values in a Livecharts `CartesianChart`. But value binding is not working.

I am using `LiveCharts 0.9.7` and `.NET 4.5`

I went through [WPF Live-Charts -- Binding Separator in Code Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50164439/wpf-live-charts-binding-separator-in-code-not-working) question but it didn't work on me since the code is different.

What I have tried is this which was in [https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Axes]:

In XAML:

```
<lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}">
    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <lvc:Axis Labels="{Binding Labels}">
            <lvc:Axis.Separator>
               <lvc:Separator IsEnabled="False" Step="{Binding Step}"></lvc:Separator>
            </lvc:Axis.Separator>
        </lvc:Axis>
    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
       <lvc:Axis Title="Sold Items" LabelFormatter="{Binding YFormatter}"></lvc:Axis>
    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
</lvc:CartesianChart>
```

In CS:

```
 public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
 public string[] Labels { get; set; }
 public Func<double, string> YFormatter { get; set; }
 public int Step { get; set; }
```

Here `Step` is the separator step value and it can be changed in runtime.
Every other bindings are working properly.

No error is given and X-axis separators are also displayed but not according to the `Step` value.

Kindly expect your help to fix this out!!

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in the getter of the `Step` property? Is it hit? How come the binding to `Formatter` work when the property is called `YFormatter`? Do you really bind to the correct object?

Comment: @mm8 Y was missed and I edited that part. Thank you. Actually `YFormatter`, `Label and` `SeriesCollection` bindings are working properly. Only the `Step` binding is not working and I cannot understand what is the reason. I'll debug and check.

Comment: Found the problem. Problem was the binding values of the `Step`. I have used 0, 500, 1000, 1500, ... , 15000 values to X axis and used 5000 as the `Step` value. Since the count of X axis values is less than 5000, we cannot see the separator. Now it is working.